# `if` fails to check value of an <img> src

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, src

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. The `if` doesn't seem to be working in this case. I'd like the image to change when people click on the button. Can somebody help me please?

```
<body>

<div>
    <img id="en_garde" src="gifattaque/gif1.png">
</div>
<br>
<button onclick=attaque_animation() type="button">Attaque</button>


<script>
    function attaque_animation() {
        if (document.getElementById("en_garde").src=="gifattaque/gif1.png") {
            document.getElementById("en_garde").src="gifattaque/gif2.png";

        }


    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work when you quote the attribute value? (`onclick="attaque...()"`)

Comment: Try `console.log(document.getElementById("en_garde").src)` to see what the `.src` property resolves to

Comment: You might be missing the location `hostname` and `protocol` ie- absolute url of the image (http://yourdomain.com/file/gifattaque/gif1.png). So try to add it to the image path and then compare it.

Comment: It would probably help if you wrote valid HTML.

Answer (score 5):

The `src` property will be expanded to the *full* image source (including `http://...`), and so won't exactly match the value you're looking for.

You're better off checking the *end* of the property:

```
if (document.getElementById("en_garde").src.match(/gifattaque\/gif1\.png$/))
  document.getElementById("en_garde").src = "gifattaque/gif2.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

to  select the element you can use:

```
document.querySelector('[src$="gif1.png"]')
```

it will check for src attr ending with "gif1.png".

```js
var el = document.querySelector('[src$="gif1.png"]');
   
if (el)
el.src="gifattaque/gif2.png";

console.log(el)
```